# Perl debugger for locating a subroutine call

Tags: perl, debugging

I'm running perl -d on some script. the script uses some sub which causes it to crash, how can I find where the script actually calls that sub? (it could be in any of the modules the script uses, not only the script itself)

Comment: Do you know the name of the sub that's causing the crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Devel::Trace module. You should be able to trace program execution with it.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `T` command to print the stack trace after a crash. Use the `t` command to toggle tracing during execution.

All of this is documented in the debugger online help - `h` command.